# Django missing labels fromset

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

My Django learning has brought me to Forms.  I've been able to create a simple form, using the information from the book I'm reading.  I've also create a form based on the Model I have created.  The issue I am having is that I am trying to create my own formatting within the template and for some reason the label information isn't held within the formset.  I'm a little confused at how using the default way of displaying this i.e. {{ form }} has this information.

What I have;

adminforms.py

```
class NewsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News_Article
        exclude = ('news_datetime_submitted', 'news_yearmonth', )
        labels = {
            'news_title': _('Enter News Title'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'news_title': _('Enter a title to give a short description of what the news is.'),
        }
        error_messages = {
            'news_title': {
                'max_length': _("News title is too long."),
            },
        }
```

view.py

```
def create(request, dataset):
    if dataset not in ['news', 'announcement']:
        # change this to the siteadmin page if authenticated and have permissions, otherwise go to home
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pages'))
    rDict = {}
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        if dataset == "news":
            form = NewsForm(request.POST)
        elif dataset == "announcement":
            form = AnnouncementForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            pass

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        announcement = get_announcement()
        if not announcement == None:
            rDict['announcement'] = announcement
        if dataset == "news":
            rDict['formset'] = NewsForm()
            rDict['branding'] = {'heading': 'Create News Item', 'breadcrumb': 'Create News', 'dataset': 'create/' + dataset + '/'}
        elif dataset == "announcement":
            rDict['form'] = AnnouncementForm()
            rDict['branding'] = {'heading': 'Create Announcement', 'breadcrumb': 'Create Announcement', 'dataset': 'create/' + dataset + '/'}
        rDict['sitenav'] = clean_url(request.path, ['"', "'"])
        rDict['menu'] = Menu.objects.all().order_by('menu_position')
        pdb.set_trace()
        return render(request, 'en/public/admin/admin_create.html', rDict)
```

template

```
<form action="/siteadmin/{{ branding.dataset }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For some reason jut get the form fields and no label information. N.b. The template text I've gottom from the Django documentation on formsets.

I've taken a look at the data thats returned and no label information is in it, yet it works with just {{ form }} ?  Bit confused.

```
(Pdb) rDict['formset']
<NewsForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(news_title;news_text;news_active)>
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a context variable named "formset" which is not a formset, it's a form: `rDict['formset'] = NewsForm()`.

So, when this context variable is passed to the template, iterating with `{% for form in formset %}` has the misleading effect of creating a variable named `form` which is actually a form field. Try naming things properly (if you actually want a formset, create one as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/)) and see if things start making sense.

Comment: Thanks @david-g.  I'd got myself confused when trying to work out how to manually create my form within my template.  I'm not after a formset and didnt realise how to access each element of the form.  Your input has lead me to work this out so thank you.  I'm still working my way through my books so slowly picking things up (even more so with the excellent responses from people who have been taking the time to reply to me here).  Don't really have any close friends who understands Django who can mentor me so this resource is invaluable.  Thanks again :)